# R could not find function 'circleGrob'

Tags: r

I am currently using the library `ggplot2` in R.
I have a R script here which then uses a function called `circleGrob`
When trying to do so, R gives an Error and says that the function is unknown.

Heres the whole line:

```
annotation_custom( grob=circleGrob( r=unit (2 , " npc " ) ) , xmin=2, xmax=4, ymin=4, ymax=6)
```

The script is a few years old. So might it be that this function is deprecated? If so with what has it been replaced?
Or is there something I need to install in R in order to use this function?

Comment: `library(grid)`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Couldn't find anything here or with google ..

Comment: You're welcome. Using `??circleGrob` (note two `??`) is sometimes useful if you don't know the function: it will do a fuzzy search through your installed packages looking for the term.